# How can I use the xlwings in flask?

Tags: python, flask, ctypes, xlwings

I have a VBA Macro named Proj_Result. I can use it in Spyder by import xlwings.
My code is following:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.books('Macro_for_Proj_Result.xlsm')
pr = wb.macro('Proj_Result')
result=pr(ws1, runno1, prod_name1, spcode, result_type, var, r.date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
print(result)
```

I run the python script and get the correct result.
I want use this code in web application so I use flask framestructure.
The code is same as in spyder but I get a error on this line:

```
wb = xw.books('Macro_for_Proj_Result.xlsm')
```

And the error is following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lapydev\jspt\views.py", line 428, in getvariable
    getAIOdata(md5_code,left_result,middle_result,right_result)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lapydev\jspt\views.py", line 440, in getAIOdata
    getVardata(aioParams,left_result[0][0])
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lapydev\jspt\views.py", line 446, in getVardata
    wb = xw.books(os.path.join(jspt.static_folder, 'Macro_for_Proj_Result.xlsm'))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings-0.11.4-py3.5.egg\xlwings\main.py", line 49, in __call__
    return self._wrap(impl=self.impl(name_or_index))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings-0.11.4-py3.5.egg\xlwings\main.py", line 2828, in impl
    return apps.active.books.impl
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings-0.11.4-py3.5.egg\xlwings\main.py", line 358, in books
    return Books(impl=self.impl.books)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings-0.11.4-py3.5.egg\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 374, in books
    return Books(xl=self.xl.Workbooks)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings-0.11.4-py3.5.egg\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 302, in xl
    self._xl = get_xl_app_from_hwnd(self._hwnd)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings-0.11.4-py3.5.egg\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 218, in get_xl_app_from_hwnd
    ptr = accessible_object_from_window(child_hwnd)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings-0.11.4-py3.5.egg\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 189, in accessible_object_from_window
    byref(IDispatch._iid_), byref(ptr))
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 920, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147467259] 未指定的错误
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO in __init__ [C:/inetpub/wwwroot/lapydev/__init__.py:65]:
hello 500!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I use the web server of pycharm.
How can I use the xlwings in flask?
Thank you very much!

Comment: In flask I have attempt this method but the same error:  wb = xw.books(os.path.join(jspt.static_folder, 'Macro_for_Proj_Result.xlsm'))

Comment: And I have put the file Macro_for_Proj_Result.xlsm in jspt.static_folder and open it. My config for jspt.static_folder is : jspt=Blueprint('jspt',__name__,template_folder='templates',static_folder='../static')